# Does ISKCON advocate birth-based caste-system or guṇa-based? And on what basis?

Tags: caste-system, varna, gunas, iskcon, purusha-sukta

What type of caste-system (varṇāśrama) does ISKCON advocate? Birth-based or guṇa-based? And on what basis?

If they believe one's varṇa is based on their guṇa:

1. Do they reject smṛtis such as Manu which seem to advocate birth-based varṇāśrama?
2. Also, how do they interpret the Puruṣa-sūkta verse *brāhmaṇo 'sya mukham ... padbhyāṃ śūdro ajāyata* (brāhmaṇa was born from Puruṣa's mouth ... śūdra from his feet)?

Answer (score 5):

**What type of caste-system (varṇāśrama) does ISKCON advocate? Birth-based or guṇa-based?**

It seems ISKCON advocates guna based caste-system as mentioned in this commentary:

> Herein it is clearly stated by Nārada Muni that one should not be accepted as a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, vaiśya or śūdra according to birth, for although this is going on now, it is not accepted by the śāstras. As stated in Bhagavad-gītā (4.13), cātur-varṇyaṁ mayā sṛṣṭaṁ guṇa-karma-vibhāgaśaḥ. Thus the four divisions of society — brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, vaiśya and śūdra — are to be ascertained according to qualities and activities. ~ [Commentary on SB 7.11.35](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/11/35)

**And on what basis?**

As mentioned in the above commentary mostly it's based on SB 7.11, BG 4.13. The above link has more detailed commentary and SB verse.

Comment: Yes, they follow guna based caste system.